# How to find bot's conversationId when testing in Azure Portal WebChat console?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have built a bot service in Azure. And currently, I am also testing in the test webchat in Azure portal.

What I need to know is how in this conversation (or via the botbuilder sdk) do I find the conversation ID.

I have a separate script that wants to send messages via directline to this already open conversation in Azure Portal but it needs the conversation ID.

Nowhere in the code for my bot does it specify starting a conversation either - it listens via the builder.UniversalBot(connector).

I know how to start and have a conversation all via directline with this bot. But I would like to start a conversation in the webchat in the Azure portal, find the conversation id and then use that in the other script I have to post messages to that same conversation.

Presumably, when I start a conversation by messaging in the webchat, there is a conversation started?

Help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried connecting your bot to the Bot Framework Emulator for testing? The Emulator has a debug panel which shows additional details about the JSON message object. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes I have tried this. I have managed to get the conversation id but I can't use it the same way I do with normal conversation ID's when the conversation is solely via direct line. That's the issue. So, I was thinking I was perhaps getting the wrong conversation id. As I seem to be getting the correct id, the issue is now how do I post to it via direct line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the conversation id in the Network tab of Chrome's developer tools:

[image]

Another option is to just have the bot show the conversation id:

```
bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    if(session.message.text == 'get conversationid')
        session.send('conversation.id: ' + session.message.address.conversation.id);
    else
        session.send('You said: ' + session.message.text);

});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response - this conversation id doesn't seem to be findable when using postman - {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "Unknown conversation"
    }
}

I am using a GET request

https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/9323c31ab1ba42328edc9191621f9c9c/activities

Comment: I have also tried a GET with this https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/9323c31ab1ba42328edc9191621f9c9c/activities

Comment: Your original question was about retrieving the conversation id from the azure portal with webchat.  If you are need assistance using that conversation id to send a message, please post a new question with the code you've tried.